# OpenRefine, how to merge row X values based on row Y unique value

Tags: openrefine

In OpenRefine, how can I go from this:

```
ID    criteria  
=====.============
40006 John Doe|1985-05-15
50008 John Doe|1985-05-15  
23012 John Doe|1985-05-15
90001 Ferry Hart|1978-09-23
 9031 Ferry Hart|1978-09-23
```

to this:

```
ID's                criteria
===================.=================== 
40006, 50008, 23012 John Doe|1985-05-15
90001, 9031         Ferry Hart|1978-09-23
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771354/1016065) looks like the right answer. Blanking down does produce this:

```
ID    criteria  
=====.============
40006 John Doe|1985-05-15
50008 
23012
90001 Ferry Hart|1978-09-23
 9031
```

But *Join multi-valued cells* on ID doesn't seem to work. This might be because all my rows are also records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466974/open-refine-regroup-rows-values-by-column-values).

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the matter is that you can turn sets of distinct rows - that is, rows with their own unique serial number in the `All` column - into records by blanking *if and only if* the column you're blanking down is at the beginning.

(Let's say 'a record' is a row with a serial number plus some rows below it with no serial number, that belong to the record. )

What follows below is derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67472022/1016065), thanks to [magdmartin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329758/magdmartin). Here are the steps.

1. Make sure the criteria column is trimmed and that you're in row mode
2. criteria -> edit column -> move column to the beginning.
3. criteria -> edit cells -> blank down. This turns sets of rows into records.
4. switch to record mode. You'll now see records: only rows with a criteria have a serial number.
5. ID -> add column based on this column, enter this GREL:

   `forEach(row.record.cells['ID'].value,v,v).join('|')`

   That creates the desired field contents. You can blank that down too.
6. criteria -> Facet -> Customized Facet -> Facet by blank (null or empty string)
7. All -> Facet -> Facet by blanks to select only empty rows
8. All -> Edit rows -> remove matching rows
9. In the Facet box on the left, select the remaining rows.

Yay!